# Altair bar chart with dropdown- keeping bar width same both with selection and without

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I am trying to create a chart in Altair with dropdowns. Here's the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Merc","US",500, "Car_A"], ["BMW","US" ,55, "Car_B"]
                   , ["BMW","US",40, "Car_C"], ["Merc", "China",650, "Car_D"]
                  , ["BMW","US",80, "Car_E"], ["Merc", "China",850, "Car_F"]], columns=list("ABCD"))

position_dropdown_Type = alt.binding_select(name = "Type:" , options=[None] + list(df["B"].unique()), labels = ['All'] + list(df["B"].unique()))
position_selection_Type = alt.selection_single(fields=['B'], bind=position_dropdown_Type)

position_dropdown_1_Car = alt.binding_select(name = "Company:", options=[None] + list(df["A"].unique()), labels = ['All'] + list(df["A"].unique()))
position_selection_1_Car = alt.selection_single(fields=['A'], bind=position_dropdown_1_Car, name = "__")

#interval = alt.selection_multi(fields=['GICS_SUB_IND'], bind='legend')
Car_bar=alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
            color = 'A',   
            y = alt.Y('C', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 1.2*df["C"].max()]),
                      title = 'Range'),
            x = alt.X('D:O', sort = alt.EncodingSortField(field="C", order='ascending', op='max'), title = 'Care_Name')
             ).add_selection(interval).add_selection(position_selection_Type).transform_filter(position_selection_Type).add_selection(position_selection_1_Car).transform_filter(position_selection_1_Car)

(Car_bar).properties(width = 700)
```

the code works with a graph like this when all values are selected
[image]

However, when I make a selection, the bar width takes the entire width as seen below
[image]

Defining size inside *mark_bar(size = 10)* is not an option as the code will be accessing different datasets with wide range of sample size. Also, since the dropdown list will be quite long, selecting from the legend is also not ideal.

Is there a way to keep the width same for the bars with the selection from dropdown?

*edited - removing the properties option at the end also does not solve the issue*

Answer (score 2):

It seem the issue is with the `properties(width = 700)` setting. It is forcing the bar width to be large enough to satisfy the width setting. If you remove that, it will give adapt the bar width accordingly.

*Edit: Output plot*
[image]

Comment: i had tried that options but it didn't work for me

Comment: It is giving me the result you are looking for. It might be related to coding environment. I ran the code in a python 3.8.5 with altair 4.2.0.

Comment: thanks, I am on 3.8.6 but on Jupyter Lab. Probably, something to do with that

Comment: @GreenFinance This answer should work for you in JupyterLab on Python 3.8.6 also. Double check that you are on Altair 4.2.0 and try restarting JupyterLab as well since there might be some previous cell you have executed that affects things (e.g. the `interval` variable in your example is undefined, and should be replaced by one of the selections you defined)

Comment: thanks @joelostblom 
Not sure of the issue. I removed the interval variable and I am also  running Altair 4.2.0